# Uniform integrability of the maximum of a random walk with negative drift

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-walk, uniform-integrability

Given $S_k^{(n)} = X_1^{(n)} + ... + X_k^{(n)}$ for all $k,n\in\mathbb{N}$, where the  $X_i^{(n)}$'s are iid with mean $-\gamma$  for some $\gamma > 0$ and unit variance. Let 
\begin{equation}M^{(n)} = \max_k S^{(n)}_k\end{equation}
I have so far proven that $M^{(n)}$ converges in distribution to a random variable $M$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. However, I would also like to show that $\mathbb{E}M^{(n)}\rightarrow \mathbb{E}M$ for which I need the uniform integrability of $M^{(n)}$. Does this hold true under these conditions?

Comment: Did you manage to see whether there is a bound independent of $n$ of $\mathbb E|M^{(n)}|$?

Comment: I do not have an upper bound on $\mathbb{E}|M^{(n)}|$ (yet) no. I presume you suggest using dominated convergence?

Comment: And yes, I meant $\gamma>0$, my mistake..

Comment: How do you show the convergence in distribution of $M^{(n)}$?